# How to avoid scanf after my signal handler function in C?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
void signal_handler(int signal) {
    printf("Caught signal in CHILD.\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int s;
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_handler);
    while(1){
         printf("%s@%s/# ",getlogin(),get_current_dir_name());
         scanf("%d",&s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i run the code it prints:

```
something: ^ZCaught signal in CHILD.
```

As far i understand that the scanf doesn't execute when i press the ctr-z. Although after the printf inside my function it goes straight to the scanf, waits for input and then starts the loop again.Is there any way to avoid scanf when i press ctr-z and start the while loop again? I tried something like that

```
void signal_handler(int signal) {
    printf("Caught signal in CHILD.\n");
    printf("%s@%s/# ",getlogin(),get_current_dir_name());
}
```

but it didn't work. After the second printf goes straight to the scanf, waits for input and then starts the loop again. Can i, somehow, start the loop again?

Comment: I'm not getting you. The code do exactly what you wrote. When you press the first time ctrl-z scanf is skypped and loop restarts.

Comment: That's my problem! Scanf doesn't skipped! and i can't understand why...

Comment: The worst code could be adding exit(1) to your signal handler. I'll post an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal handler *is* interrupting `scanf` during its `read` of STDIN.  However, because of the way you set signal disposition, the `read` system call restarts immediately upon return of the signal handler.  That's why you are "stuck" in the `scanf` rather than back at the top of your loop.

One important thing you can do is to [use `sigaction` rather than `signal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/signal.html).  This will force you to specify the behavior of interrupted calls:  restart them or not?

The next thing to do is to limit your signal handlers to functions that are [async-signal-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3366361/132382), lest you risk [misery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3366361/132382).

As an aside, another change to make is to give us all the required includes (`<unistd.h>`?) and defines (`_GNU_SOURCE` ?) to make your program work.

Answer (score 0):

As commented the worst solution should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    printf("Caught signal in CHILD.\n");
    exit(1);

}

int main(void) {
    int s;
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_handler);
    while(1){
         printf("test\n");
         scanf("%d",&s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Better solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static volatile int keepRunning = 1;

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    printf("Caught signal in CHILD.\n");
    keepRunning = 0;

}

int main(void) {
    int s;
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_handler);
    while(keepRunning){
         printf("test\n");
         scanf("%d",&s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT after comments**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static volatile int skipPrintf= 1;

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    printf("Caught signal in CHILD.\n");
    skipPrintf= 1;

}

int main(void) {
    int s;
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_handler);
    while(1){
         if (skipPrintf == 0)
         {
             printf("test\n");
         }
         else
         {
             skipPrintf = 0;
         }
         scanf("%d",&s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well with exit the program terminates. I want to start over again the while loop. I want to after the ctr-z is pressed to print again test,as your example, and then the scanf waits for input. Unbelievable!!! i've never seen someone to use volatile! Thanks for your help

Comment: In this case volatile is mandatory, because of is keepRunning is modified in  t handler and main.

Comment: @Csd I really not getting you. The code you posted exec exactly as you want. After a ctrl-z redo printf and go to scanf.

Comment: But i don't want to go to the scanf! i Want to start the while loop again from the start.

Comment: @Csd Is what your posted code do. printf --> wait for scanf -->press ctrl-z --> go to signal handler---> printf egain-->scanf

Comment: Sory my mistake...I  meant the printf inside main

Comment: @Csd Ok. I edited and added code for you. If it's enough for you don't forget to upvote and check as answered.