# Why VTune fails with error `[Instrumentation Engine]: __libc_thread_freeres()`?

Tags: c++, profiling, glibc, intel-vtune

I am trying to profile my application using vtune to identify some hotspots. The profiling starts and in a couple of seconds it fails:

```
ahadji05@myhome ~/Desktop/myapp (master) $ vtune -collect hotspots -verbose /bin/myapp
vtune: Collection started. To stop the collection, either press CTRL-C or enter from another console window: vtune -r /Desktop/myapp/r000hs -command stop.
vtune: Error: [Instrumentation Engine]: __libc_thread_freeres() is not suitable for probed function insertion.
vtune: Collection failed.
vtune: Internal Error
```

I am using:

- Intel OneAPI 2021.3.0.
- Compiler `icpx`
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux, 8.9
- Target x86-64

Based on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701888/how-can-i-find-out-the-source-of-this-glibc-backtrace-originating-with-clone) as far as I understand this is malloc-internal related to threads allocation/free. I do not use any threads in my application so I am wondering where could this error come from?

*I get the same message if I run the profiling from the GUI.

Comment: Maybe the main thread.